# Is there a cost difference between returning a function by reference vs passing the object through a void function?

Tags: c++

When would you choose to prefer one way over the other? When I ran the bottom example through Godbolt. The return by reference function calls a move at the very end. If the container being passed in was large enough would that be costly? Or would it simply move the pointers around?

Ex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
void print(const T& v)
{
  for(const auto& e : v)
    std::cout << e << " ";

  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void byVoid(std::vector<int>& v)
{
  for(auto && e : v)
    e = 0;
}

std::vector<int>& byRef(std::vector<int>& v)
{
  for(auto && e : v)
    e = 0;
  
  return v;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> test1 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  std::vector<int> test2 = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

  print(test1);
  print(test2);

  byVoid(test1);
  test2 = byRef(test2);

  print(test1);
  print(test2);
}
```

Comment: Build with optimizations enabled. Check the generated code that the calls aren't optimized away. Then add a million calls to each, measuring the total time and calculate the average time. Then compare the results.

Comment: "_The return by reference function calls a move at the very end_" - That's most probably just putting the pointer to `v` on the stack. It will be one and the same operation no matter how many elements you have in `v`.

Comment: With that said, what is the practical difference between the two `byVoid` and `byRef` functions? Both essentially do the same, and the only difference (`byRef` returning a reference to the vector) is ignored by the calling code making that difference kind of moot.

Comment: In your test code, you aren't using the returned value of the `byRef` function, so why even have it? The passed vector argument will be equally modified by both functions; the return value is a *reference* to that vector, so any "move" will just involve a single address, I would think.

Comment: *"The return by reference function calls a move at the very end."* If you mean that `byRef` moves `v` at the end of the function, it does not. Otherwise, I don't understand that statement.

Comment: @Adrian Mole you are correct. I made an edit to show I am using it correctly. That was a typo on my end.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think OP means an assembler `mov`.

Comment: Ted is correct, it is an assembler `mov` that gets called at the end of `byRef`

Comment: `test2 = byRef(test2);` does (self-)assignement of vector, it doesn't rebind the reference...

Comment: In your edited code, the assignment will cause the contents of `test2` to be copied to the contents of `test2`. But that's not the function's "fault" ... what you do with its returned reference is up to you.

Comment: @Sailanarmo In that case for *"If the container being passed in was large enough would that be costly?"* the answer is no. The cost should be unrelated to the size of the container.